# Customize ActionBar

Tags: android, themes

I have a basic theme for my app which extends the standard android *`Holo`* theme. All I have so far is:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
</style>
```

I found very little information on customizing different aspects of the action bar, such as border color, button-pressed-color, underline color etc, etc. Is there a page that lists the editable properties of the actionbar somewhere?

---

Edit:

Thanks to jansel's answer, I was able to find a large list of default properties set out in `SDKInstallationDir\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\themes.xml`. I picked out the section that listed the action bar styles and listed them below:

```
actionDropDownStyle
actionButtonStyle
actionOverflowButtonStyle
actionModeBackground
actionModeSplitBackground
actionModeCloseDrawable
actionModeCutDrawable
actionModeCopyDrawable
actionModePasteDrawable
actionModeSelectAllDrawable
actionModeShareDrawable
actionModeFindDrawable
actionModeWebSearchDrawable
actionBarTabStyle
actionBarTabBarStyle
actionBarTabTextStyle
actionModeStyle
actionModeCloseButtonStyle
actionBarStyle
actionBarSplitStyle
actionBarSize
actionModePopupWindowStyle
actionMenuTextAppearance
actionMenuTextColor
actionBarWidgetTheme
actionBarDivider
actionBarItemBackground
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't a specific page that resume all property you can change in `actionbar`, but this resources are usefully to know many of these properties, also you have the option to see the direct android framework style used for all widgets and components, these styles file are placed  in `SDKInstallationDir\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\styles.xml` and `SDKInstallationDir\platforms\android-14\data\res\values\themes.xml`.

[`Styling the Action Bar`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and [`Customizing Actionbar`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)